# React Native Bridge - exporting one function in another file in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

In `CMIconManager.m` I have a function called `getImageForIcon`.

```
  - (UIImage *)getImageForIcon:(CMIcon)icon fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize fontColor:(UIColor *)fontColor imageWidth:(CGFloat)imageWidth imageHeight:(CGFloat)imageHeight backgroundCircleColor:(UIColor *)backgroundCircleColor backgroundCircleSize:(CGFloat)backgroundCircleSize {
  // set up the squares we will be drawing in...
  CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight);
  CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
  CGSize circleSize = CGSizeMake(backgroundCircleSize, backgroundCircleSize);
  CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake((imageWidth - backgroundCircleSize) / 2, (imageHeight - backgroundCircleSize) / 2, circleSize.width, circleSize.height);

  // start the drawing context...
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  // fill the image background with transparent alpha...
  CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -imageRect.size.height);
  CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.0);
  CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height));

  // reset subsequent drawing to non-transparent...
  CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 1.0);

  // fill in a solid background circle, centered, if needed...
  if (![backgroundCircleColor isEqual:[UIColor clearColor]] || !backgroundCircleColor) {
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, backgroundCircleColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);
  }

  // draw the icon, centered in the image...
  if ([fontColor isEqual:[UIColor clearColor]]) {
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear);
  }
  NSAttributedString *theString = [self attributedStringForIcon:icon fontSize:fontSize color:fontColor];
  if (theString.length >= 1) {
    CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) (theString));
    CGFloat widthConstraint = imageWidth;
    CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, theString.length), NULL, CGSizeMake(widthConstraint, CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);
    CGFloat distanceFromTop = (imageWidth - suggestedSize.height) / 2;
    CGFloat distanceFromLeft = (imageHeight - suggestedSize.width) / 2;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(distanceFromLeft, distanceFromTop, suggestedSize.width, suggestedSize.height));
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
    CTFrameDraw(frame, ctx);
    CFRelease(frame);
    CFRelease(path);
    CFRelease(frameSetter);
  }

  // save the current context in a UIImage object...
  UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return finalImage;
}
```

---

How do I pass this function to `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()` in the new file: `RNIconManager.m`?

```
#import "RNIconManager.h"
#import "CMIconManager.h"

@implementation RNIconManager
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

CMIconManager *getIcons = [[CMIconManager alloc] init];

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getImageForIcon:(UIImage*)icon
                  fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
                  fontColor:(UIColor *)fontColor
                  imageWidth:(CGFloat)imageWidth
                  imageHeight:(CGFloat)imageHeight
                  backgroundCircleColor:(UIColor *)backgroundCircleColor
                  backgroundCircleSize:(CGFloat)backgroundCircleSize
                  callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback)
{
  callback(@[getIcons(icon, fontSize, fontColor,imageWidth, imageHeight, backgroundCircleColor, backgroundCircleSize)]);
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that `getImageForIcon` is instance method but you are using this like class method.

Comment: That's very possible. I'm completely new to Objective C and I may be using it more like JavaScript. What would the difference be in Objective C?

Comment: Change '-(UIImage *)' to '+(UIImage *)', but there is no effective way to send data from class method to a instance. I used 'NSNotificatio' instead.

Comment: Updated the code, still doesn't work but I think that's how to use an instance method, right?

Answer (score 0):

The `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` macro takes the whole method signature as a parameter, so it would look something like this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getImageForIcon:(UIImage*)icon
                  fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
                  fontColor:(UIColor *)fontColor
                  imageWidth:(CGFloat)imageWidth
                  imageHeight:(CGFloat)imageHeight
                  backgroundCircleColor:(UIColor *)backgroundCircleColor
                  backgroundCircleSize:(CGFloat)backgroundCircleSize)
{
    //your function content goes here
}
```

**A couple of notes:**

1. You can't just use any type in your methods. You can only use types that RN knows how to convert, so you can't use `CMIcon`.
2. You can't simply return values from exported methods. If you need to return something you'll need to pass a callback or use promises.
3. If the actual function that you wish to call is found in another class you'll still need to do the export as I mentioned, but inside this exported method you can call another method - it may be a static method or an instance method according to how your code is written.

You should really check out the documentation for [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html), it has all the info and examples you need.

**Edit:**
Here's an example of how you can expose a class method that you can call statically:

```
//in your h file
@interface CMIconManager : NSObject
+ (UIImage*)getImageForIcon:(UIImage*)icon fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize fontColor:(UIColor *)fontColor imageWidth:(CGFloat)imageWidth imageHeight:(CGFloat)imageHeight backgroundCircleColor:(UIColor *)backgroundCircleColor backgroundCircleSize:(CGFloat)backgroundCircleSize callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback;
@end

//in your m file
@implementation CMIconManager
+ (void)getImageForIcon:(UIImage*)icon fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize fontColor:(UIColor *)fontColor imageWidth:(CGFloat)imageWidth imageHeight:(CGFloat)imageHeight backgroundCircleColor:(UIColor *)backgroundCircleColor backgroundCircleSize:(CGFloat)backgroundCircleSize callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback
{
    //your implementation
}
@end

//call the method
[CMIconManager getImageForIcon:icon fontSize:size fontColor:color imageWidth:width imageHeight:height backgroundCircleColor:backgroundColor backgroundCircleSize:circleSize callback:callback];
```

Comment: Thanks @Artal, I've read the documentation on Native Modules but I'm lacking in Objective C understanding. However I understand the first two points you made here. So I made changes in my code. The function listed above is a function found in another class that I wish to reuse and call on the JS end. How can I call this method in this new class inside the callback? With the updated code, I see errors "Called object type 'CMIconManager *' is not a function or a function pointer." and "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant."

Comment: You can't create an instance of an object floating in your code, that's why you're getting the error `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant`. In addition, you're trying to use this instance as a call to a method and even so - this is not the syntax for calling instance methods in Objective C. You will need to either put your code inside the `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD`, or you can turn `getImageForIcon` into a class method so you can call it statically.

Comment: @Turnipdabeets I edited my answer to provide an example of how you can call your method statically. You should know though that you're going to encounter additional issues since it's not possible to pass a `UIImage` object over the bridge, only serializable types are allowed. You will need to either save it to a file and provider a URL, or you can look how other RN classes do it internally, I think they have some kind of helper class to handle it.

Comment: Thanks @Artal. This is a brownfield app and I'm trying to reuse the already implimented Icon Manager in the RN part of the app. So, my concern is that if I change getImageForIcon from an instance method to a class method, won't that cause other issues in the app itself previously using this method? Would this mean I'd have no choice but to use a less DRY approach and copy and paste that whole instance method inside RCT_EXPORT_METHOD? And since this function is returning a UIImage, it looks like I might have to use requireNativeComponent and RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY, right?

Comment: Since your method doesn't access any instance methods or properties it is easy to covert it to static and then also change the method calls in the rest of the app (don't worry, the compiler will let you know if you missed something). Regarding the image - it's not related to view property, it's pretty much what I wrote, and it's probably a topic to a whole different question..